# Where are coordinate system files saved when using the ArcGIS Citrix app?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, citrix

Is there a standard location where coordinate systems are saved within ArcGIS when using a Citrix app? Or maybe a redirected folder location?

Comment: I think Esri stopped including the .prj files at version 10.1.  They are now referenced using well-known IDs (WKID).

Comment: http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39488

Comment: Do you mean ones added to "Favorites"? I think I've seen a similar question on GeoNet or the older Esri forums...but I can't find it.

Comment: Not adding projections to the Favorites within ArcCatalog or ArcMap, but where the actual directory of coordinate system/projection files are located that come with ArcGIS. Specifically for the Citrix app version of ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same for all cases of ArcGIS running on Citrix, but the location for the coordinate system/projection files is generally located at the following for a user on a network:

\[server name that Citrix is running on]\citrix redirected[user name]\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Coordinate Systems

and similarly for custom transformation files:
\[server name that Citrix is running on]\citrix redirected[user name]\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\CustomTransformations